# Орест чи ОрЕст, ГарАсим чи ГарасИм, ПрокІп чи ПрОкіп?

Tags: власні-назви, наголос

Здебільшого усі наголошую так: ***О*рест, Гар*А*сим, Прок**І**п.**

До сьогодні наголошувала аналогічно. Проте тільки що знайшла інформацію в Ірини Фаріон [МОВНА НОРМА: ЗНИЩЕННЯ, ПОШУК, ВІДНОВА](http://slovoprosvity.org/2009/04/30/2067-old/), що ці наголоси не нормативні. Тому, на її думку, має бути так:

**ОрЕст, ГарасИм, ПрОкіп.**

Чи справді це так? Чи ще десь зафіксовані саме такі наголоси?

Comment: А Ірина Фаріон посилається на поважні джерела? Бо якщо ні, то мінусів би нахапалася на нашому сайті. :-) А якщо серйозно, то сам термін *нормативність* — це термін, який вимагає цілком наукового обґрунтування. На жаль, у наведеній статті містяться посилання на кшталт [4, с.123], але нема покажчика літератури.

Comment: От власне! У зв’язку з тим, що посилань на джерела я не знайшла, аби переконатися, тому і запитую тут, чи десь справді такі варіанти зафіксовані. Якщо так, то де саме? Маю ще монографію її у паперовому вигляді, але видання друге, доповнене, там теж нема посилань, лише підтема "1.4.9. Наголошення власних імен" і подана та інформація, яку скопіювала сюди.

Comment: Є байка про шановного академіка Л.А.Булаховського. На  одній із конференцій він , обгрунтовуючи лінгвістичні достідження, наводив якісь недоладні приклади. Один із присутніх заперечив: "Л.А., але так ніхто не говорить" - "Значить усі говорять неправильно". Це той самий випадок...

Comment: Можливо і так... :-) Тоді, мабуть, це лиш науковий погляд п. Ірини і можна наголошувати і так, і так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ім'я **Орест** походить з грецької, де має  наголос на "Е" [Ορέστης(Орестeс)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orestes).

Ім'я **Гарасим** походить також від грецького [Γεράσιμος(Герасимос)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerasimus_of_the_Jordan), наголос падає на другий склад. [[джерело]](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC)

Щодо Прокопа, у [словнику відмінків](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF) наголос падає на перший склад, проте у повному грецькому варіанті - Прокопіус - наголос падає на другий склад [(Προκόπιος)](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%86%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%BF%CF%82_%CE%A0%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%BF%CF%82_%CE%BF_%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%B3%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%AC%CF%81%CF%84%CF%85%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%82).

Comment: Перепрошую, але грецькі оригінали — не аргумент (чи принаймні не остаточний аргумент). Слова часто запозичуються з іншим наголосом. Згадати хоча б _Тара́с_, що в грецькій _Τάρας_.

Comment: Звичайно, це більше питання самовизначення. Знайомий з вихідцем з Угорщини, що називає себе Орест з наголосом на перший склад. При цьому чув, як в Україні називали Орестом з наголосом на другий. Я вважаю, що строгих правил наголошення запозичених  імен не має бути. Тому й відповів згідно з витоками імен.

Answer (score 2):

Словник-довідник ["Власні імена людей"](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/ua/elib.exe?Z21ID=&I21DBN=UKRLIB&P21DBN=UKRLIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=online_book&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=FF=&S21STR=ukr0001272) містить 3 статті імен

[image: Прокоп]

[image: Орест]

[image: Герасим]

[image: Гарасим]

Ці ж імена дивимося в Словнику відмінків:

[Про́кіп](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF), [Оре́ст](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), [Гера́сим](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC_(%D1%96%D0%BC%27%D1%8F))

> Гераси́м, Гараси́м - давнє християнське ім'я.

Отже, Про́кі́п (наголос можливий на перший та другий склад), Оре́ст.
А ось ім'я Герасим в різних джерелах має різний наголос Гера́сим та Гераси́м.
Більшість варіантів з наголос на останній склад, на мою думку, так правильніше.

Comment: Але ж «Словник відмінків» (точніше, як я розумію, це «Словники України on-line» від УМІФ і їхній передрук на uk.worldwidedictionary.org) дає наголос Гера́сим.

Comment: @Sasha виправила.